# Getting an error in postgresql where column name cannot be found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am getting the following error in my Heroku logs when a query in my rails application is being invoked :

```
2019-03-19T02:16:25.782434+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-19T02:16:25.782337 #4]  INFO -- : [75c3a8ff-f6cb-4954-8f23-071bfc2671ec] Started GET "/patients?utf8=
%E2%9C%93&Full_Name=tester" for 95.45.117.131 at 2019-03-19 02:16:25 +0000
2019-03-19T02:16:25.783395+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-19T02:16:25.783337 #4]  INFO -- : [75c3a8ff-f6cb-4954-8f23-071bfc2671ec] Processing by PatientsContro
ller#index as HTML
2019-03-19T02:16:25.783570+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-19T02:16:25.783521 #4]  INFO -- : [75c3a8ff-f6cb-4954-8f23-071bfc2671ec]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
"Full_Name"=>"tester"}
2019-03-19T02:16:25.790532+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-03-19T02:16:25.790467 #4] DEBUG -- : [75c3a8ff-f6cb-4954-8f23-071bfc2671ec]   User Load (3.7ms)  SELECT
 "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]

2019-03-19T02:16:25.794827+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-03-19T02:16:25.794753 #4] DEBUG -- : [75c3a8ff-f6cb-4954-8f23-071bfc2671ec]    (3.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "patients" WHERE (full_name LIKE '%tester%' AND user_id = 5)
2019-03-19T02:16:25.795077+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-03-19T02:16:25.795025 #4]  INFO -- : [75c3a8ff-f6cb-4954-8f23-071bfc2671ec] Completed 500 Internal Serve
r Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 6.9ms)
2019-03-19T02:16:25.795954+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-03-19T02:16:25.795899 #4] FATAL -- : [75c3a8ff-f6cb-4954-8f23-071bfc2671ec]
2019-03-19T02:16:25.796028+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-03-19T02:16:25.795980 #4] FATAL -- : [75c3a8ff-f6cb-4954-8f23-071bfc2671ec] ActiveRecord::StatementInval
id (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "full_name" does not exist
2019-03-19T02:16:25.796030+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "patients" WHERE (full_name LIKE '%test...
2019-03-19T02:16:25.796032+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-03-19T02:16:25.796033+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "patients.Full_Name".
2019-03-19T02:16:25.796035+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "patients" WHERE (full_name LIKE '%tester%' AND user_id = 5)):
2019-03-19T02:16:25.796102+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-03-19T02:16:25.796057 #4] FATAL -- : [75c3a8ff-f6cb-4954-8f23-071bfc2671ec]
2019-03-19T02:16:25.796180+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-03-19T02:16:25.796138 #4] FATAL -- : [75c3a8ff-f6cb-4954-8f23-071bfc2671ec] app/controllers/patients_con
troller.rb:15:in `index'
2019-03-19T02:16:25.796617+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/patients?utf8=%E2%9C%93&Full_Name=tester" host=pure-reef-79084.herokuapp.com reques
t_id=75c3a8ff-f6cb-4954-8f23-071bfc2671ec fwd="95.45.117.131" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
```

the code being executed is this :

**patients_controller.rb**

```
@patients = Patient.where("patients.Full_Name LIKE :name AND patients.user_id = :id", {:name => "%#{params[:Full_Name]}%", :id => current_user.id})
```

I have narrowed it down to the fact that postgresql is case sensitive so i am assuming it does not like "Full_Name". I tried encapsulating the column name in double quotes like this :

```
@patients = Patient.where(""Full_Name" LIKE :name AND user_id = :id", {:name => "%#{params[:Full_Name]}%", :id => current_user.id})
```

however I get a SyntaxError. Anyone have any suggestions how i would amend this query so that it will fetch the column?

**Solved**
As per the answer below I had to put quotes around my column name like so :

```
@patients = Patient.where('"Full_Name" LIKE :name AND patients.user_id = :id', {:name => "%#{params[:Full_Name]}%", :id => current_user.id})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table was probably created with double quotes around the column name `"Full_Name"` so it expects that exact capitalization. All your references to this column should be exactly like that, not `Full_Name` or `"full_name"`.

Either reference it properly, or rename your column to omit the double quotes:
`ALTER TABLE "patients" RENAME COLUMN "Full_Name" TO full_name;`

Good discussion here: http://blog.lerner.co.il/quoting-postgresql/